# Kotlin: Load/initialize next activity in the background

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity

I have an initialization activity in my app which displays the logo, then I show my next activity using

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState) // Call the parent class function
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_launcher)

    // This starts a new co-routine
    // it is important to do it this way, in order to show the UI _before_
    // all the initialization happens, otherwise launcher is pointless
    GlobalScope.launch {
        ...
        [initialization]
        ...
        startActivity(ActivityTwo)
    }
}
```

The transition takes about three seconds because of all the code that is running inside onCreate belonging to **ActivityTwo**.  Is there a way to "create" the second activity behind the scenes, and then show it.  I don't mind if the app stays on the initialization screen for those 3 seconds, but the white transition looks really ugly.

Comment: Sounds like you should refactor your code so that ActivityTwo's `onCreate` _doesn't_ do some much work.

Comment: So what are the heavy computations? Are they done in onCreate of second activity or on this launch block?

Comment: Yeah, it sounds like. the. proper solution is to move this code from second onCreate into. the initialization co-routine.  I was hoping I don't have to do it, because it initializes a lot of private variables of the second activity class.

Answer (score 0):

**`onCreate`** method is actually creating your activity. You must be doing some heavy computation if your activity is janking while rendering. If you are not satisfied with the transition between the two activities, then apply an animation between them.

Comment: That is kind of what I am trying to do.  How do you display that animation instead of the white screen?

I am quite happy to continue to display the first activity, while I "load" the second activity in memory (hidden or something).  I don't want the screen to be white in between the two activities for 3 seconds while the onCreate of the second activity is running.

Comment: You can use a Progress Bar, or as I mentioned you can put a animation between these two activities. A simple google search would suffice.

Comment: if it was that simple, I wouldn't be asking.  A progress bar or an animation has to be displayed as part of some activity.  Assume that I am displaying them in Activity1.  I updated the question with a larger code snippet. PTAL

Comment: Again, show progress in first activity, observe response and when finished, navigate to sec activity. Also if I were you, I would not use GlobalScope...

Comment: As I point out above, many private variables are initialized in the second onCreate, so moving them into initialization is problematic.

Why wouldn't you use the GlobalScope and what is the alternative?